# UIButton created in loop not clickable

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uibutton

Here's my problem:

I add several buttons to a scrollview in a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [allEventArray count]; i++) {

        UIButton *eventButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        eventButton.tag =  i + 10;

        UIImage *normalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rosterButton.png"];
        normalImage = [normalImage 
                      stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:normalImage.size.width/2 
                      topCapHeight:normalImage.size.height/2];
        [eventButton setBackgroundImage:normalImage 
                      forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [eventButton addTarget:self action:@selector(gotoThisAirport) 
                      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [drawRosterView addSubview:eventButton];
}
```

I set the frame size and other stuff later on by opening the tag property.
All the buttons appear as advertised. 
The problem is that only the first button in the view responds to clicking. The others just sit there chilling, doing nothing. How can this be? It driving me absolutely crazy!

Please help!

Comment: have you checked userInteractionEnabled property of your drawRosterView?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a view sitting on top of any of your `UIButton`s?

Comment: No views over buttons and interaction is enabled.. Driving me crazy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your UIButton isn't fully inside your UIView.

Try only adding the UIButton to UIView and set a background color for the UIView to something like `[UIColor greenColor]`. You should then see if the UIButton is partially outside of the UIView.

Also, if you add an NSLog("click") call in -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event; of the UIView, then you can click anywhere on screen and get feedback if the UIView detects the touch or not.

Comment: In XCode 4.2 simulator there is a handy new option. Under 'Debug' menu pick 'Color Blended Layers' to color your views hideous greens and reds so you don't have to manually color backgrounds to see their frames anymore.

Comment: I tried setting the UIView to green and all the buttons appear in the UIView. But the part about logging touchesBegan doesn't work. It doesn't register a click anywhere, not even on the buttons in the view that do work.

Comment: +1 May not have solved user's problem, but was a helpful answer.

Comment: Okay, finally solved it. The views are drawn inside another UIView which didn't span the entire scrollview. DUH....